# Basis of the localization of module

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian, localization, finitely-generated, free-modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring which has a identity element and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$ module.

We write $M_\mathfrak{p}$ for the localization of $M$ with respect to prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$. So does $R_\mathfrak{p}$.

And we define $R_f = R[\frac{1}{f}],\ M_f = M \otimes_R R_f$.

On Assuming (1), we want to prove (2).　 ((1) $\Rightarrow$ (2))

(1) $\forall \mathfrak{p} \in Spec(R),\ \exists f \in R- \mathfrak{p}$ s.t. $M_f$ is $R_f$ free module.

(2) $\forall \mathfrak{p} \in Spec(R),\ $ $M_\mathfrak{p}\ \ $is$\ R_\mathfrak{p}\ $free module.

But I can't do that. Please give me some help.

Comment: Let $0\to K(p)\to F_p\to M_p\to 0$ be the exact sequence given $F_p$ free and $K(p)$ be the corresponding kernel after localization where $F_p$ is of the same rank as $M_f$. You want to show $K(p)=0$ for all $p\in Spec(R)$. Assume it is not 0, then pick $0\neq m\in K(p)$. $Ann(m)\subset p_p$ is an ideal of $R_p$. Now show $(m)=0$ by localizing at an appropriate $f\in R$ to reach contradiction. It is not clear to me why you need $R$ noetherian here. Probably, the opposite direction requires noetherian property for f.p modules.

Comment: $M_f$ is $R_f$ free, so if we localize at $p$, we have $M_p$ is $R_p$ free. (1) $\implies$ (2) is easy, do you actually want to show the opposite direction ?

Comment: @chankifung I actually would like to see why the opposite is true. Does it require noetherian property here? As I recall, $M_p$ is projective over local ring if only if it is free which requires noetherian and f.g.

Comment: @user45765, To prove the opposite, we should try to find an exact sequence $0\to K \to F \to M_f \to C \to 0$  with $K_p=C_p=0$, and if $K$ and $C$ are finitely generated, then we can find $f'$ such that $K_{f'}=C_{f'}=0$. I think we need Noetherian hypothesis to guarantee $K$ is f.g.

Comment: @chankifung my proof above does not find $K$ needs to be f.g somehow. Did I make a mistake above then? You can choose $F$ same rank as $F_f$ given $p\in Spec(R)$. I thought it suffices to argue $K_f=0$ for some $f$ and after localization.

Comment: @user45765, how do you find $f$ such that $K_f=0$ without $K$ being finitely generated?

Comment: @chankifung Yes. You are right. There is no reason to believe such $f$ exists if $K$ is not f.g.